# Adjust string to display singular or plural words

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am displaying the number of likes an image has. I want to avoid the typical '1 Likes', without success. This is my current code. The problem is that the app crashes if I use this code, although it looks fine to me. The datasource is an `NSMutableArray` that only contains numbers.

```
if ([[mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    likesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section], @"Like"];
} else {
    likesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section], @"Likes"];
}
```

Crash Log:

```
-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000023
2014-08-28 02:27:12.146 App[8886:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000023'
```

Comment: If your source array "only contains numbers", then why the heck are you treating one of its members as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the value you are getting is not a NSString but __NSCFNumber. Try just doing something like this:

```
 if ([[mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue] == 1) {
    likesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section], @"Like"];
} else {
    likesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section], @"Likes"];
}
```